# Add a custom text in WooCommerce login and registration page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-registration

In WooCommerce login/registration page, I try to add a statement "Ask for help" under the login/registration form next to "Forget password?"

To let the unregistered user go easily to the "Contact Us" when pressing on this statement.

Comment: Please upload your code and sample that you had tried.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't uploaded any code yet. I need help. Please

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could insert an echo. Something like this if you can locate the position on PHP when your form happens:

```
echo "<p><a href='contactus.html'>Ask for help</a></p>";
```

It's hard without seeing the code though. Maybe you can have access to the html form and can edit it from there.

Answer (score 0):

This will add the link in the appropriate places where Woocommerce provides action hooks:

```
add_action('woocommerce_login_form_end', 'custom_woocommerce_help_link_action');
add_action('woocommerce_after_lost_password_form', 'custom_woocommerce_help_link_action');
function custom_woocommerce_help_link_action() {
    echo '<p class="ask-help"><a href="http://localhost/ask-help">Ask for help</a></p>';
}
```

Obviously change the link URL to suit and style the paragraph as needed.